# What is the last marker on a Chalice Dungeon description?

Tags: bloodborne

What is the marker I circled? I know the Depth is the difficulty and the Area is obviously the area. But the circled mark can go up to 5 (but might go higher) and I am not quite sure what it means.

My guess is number of bonus rooms or rarity?

[image: Chalice Dungeon Description]

Comment: Based on what I've seen, I would guess it's the number of people that played it. Number of silhouettes can increase over time, and couple of mine chalices did that, one (closed) was visited by a friend, other one was open. Still, it's a speculation which needs testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It represents how many times the dungeon has been shared.